# Pass Json string to AWS Lambda in Step Function - JsonReaderException error

Tags: c#, .net-core, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I am attempting to use a AWS Lambda function in a Step Function. The Lambda Function works correctly when the it is tested individually and the json input is escaped. However when the input is passed to the lambda function through a step function, I am getting a JsonReaderException error. What am I doing wrong? Would the community know of a workaround for this issue?

**lambda function:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using Amazon.Lambda.Core;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

// Assembly attribute to enable the Lambda function's JSON input to be converted into a .NET class.
[assembly: LambdaSerializer(typeof(Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json.JsonSerializer))]
namespace AWSLambda1
{
    public class Function
    {
        public void PostsBasedOnOddOrEven(string input, ILambdaContext context)
        {
            var details = JObject.Parse(input);
            var postId = (int) details["id"];
            var oddOrEvenResult = (int) details["OddOrEvenPostsResult"];
        }
    }
}
```

**Input to Lambda function from Step Function:**

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "OddOrEvenPostsResult": 2
}
```

**Input to Lambda function (which works through the Visual Studio Invoke):**

```
"{ \"id\": \"1\", \"OddOrEvenPostsResult\": 2}"
```

**Exception Stack Trace:**

```
{
  "errorType": "JsonReaderException",
  "errorMessage": "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path '', line 1, position 1.",
  "stackTrace": [
    "at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadStringValue(ReadType readType)",
    "at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadAsString()",
    "at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ReadForType(JsonReader reader, JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter)",
    "at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)",
    "at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)",
    "at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize[T](JsonReader reader)",
    "at Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize[T](Stream requestStream)",
    "at lambda_method(Closure , Stream , Stream , LambdaContextInternal )"
  ]
}
```

**Lambda Function not working when it is part of Step Function**

[image: Lambda Function not working when it is part of Step Function]

**Lambda Function working when tested individually**

[image: Lambda Function working when tested individually]

Comment: Which lines throws error?  What is ILambdaContext and Posts ? Not possible to run whole program.

Comment: The code you posted is fine. The exception occurs somewhere else. Some other part of the application tries to deserialize the input, which is a JSON _object_, as a JSON _string_.

Comment: I have added more details. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Serialize your JSON to String before sending it to lambda function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since your lambda function is expecting `input` to be a `string`, the framework tries to parse the input as though it's a `string`.

However, the input is actually a JSON object, not a string.

Therefore the parser will fail with an "unexpected character" error. The parser is expecting a `"` character which would indicate the start of a string.

---

So, here's how you can fix it:

1. Declare a c# class which represents the input

   ```
   public class FunctionInput
   {
       public int id { get; set; }
       public int OddOrEvenPostsResult { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Change your function signature to expect `input` of type `FunctionInput`

   ```
   public class Function
   {    
       public void PostsBasedOnOddOrEven(FunctionInput input, ILambdaContext context)
       {
           var postId = input.id;
           var oddOrEvenResult = input.OddOrEvenPostsResult;
       }
   }
   ```

Note: you don't need to parse the input yourself.

Comment: Thank you Nicholas sizer. Sometimes it just helps to talk to the community when you have a brain freeze.

Comment: Hi, I am getting a null pointer exception while executing the above portion of the code when I am trying to put a message directly via SQS from AWS Console. But the code runs successfully when created a test event for the Functions. Can you please help me out as I am new AWS services?

Comment: After trying to Parse using newton package, this was much easier since I already new the incoming JSON keys.